# CakePHP 2.x Saving multiple models with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp, foreign-keys

I'm currently building a multi-step form submission website that involves a single form going through several steps and being updated by several users (not concurrently).  For example a student fills out and submits a form, which might get sent to a professor who needs to fill out fields for the same form, which then gets sent to the office, etc.

I have one particular form that allows a user to upload a file to it which needs to be saved to its own table in the database, and a reference column in the form table needs to point to it.  The form and the file both need to point to a mutual super-parent as well; my tables look something like this:

cores (super parent): form_type, form_stage, date_created, core_id (primary key)

forms: form_id (primary key), various form fields, core_id (foreign key -> Core[core_id]), file_id (foreign key -> File[file_id])

files: file_id (primary key), file fields, core_id (foreign key -> Core[core_id])

When the form gets to the stage where a file is uploaded, the core and form tuples already exist in their respective tables in the database, with form[core_id] -> Core[core_id] correctly.  I need, upon submission of the form at this next stage, for Form[file_id] -> File[file_id] and File[core_id] -> Core[core_id].

I don't know how to go about doing this.  I assume it's something along the lines of

```
//$this->request->data looks something like data['Core'] -> ['File'], ['Form']
//So Core is an array of arrays where File is an array of file variables,
//Form is an array of Form variable, and Core also has it's own Core variables.
//File[file_id] is NOT set as this attribute is incremented by the database.
//Core[core_id] and Form[core_id] are BOTH set since these rows already exist,
//and so File[core_id] can be set before hand too.


$this->Core->create();
$this->Core->Form->create();
$this->Core->File->create();

$this->Core->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('validate' => 'first', 'deep' => true));
```

Is this on the right track?  Does this correctly update the foreign key in Form pointing to File and the foreign key in File pointing to Core? (File and Form need to point to the same Core if I haven't made that obvious)

My Form model has:

```
$belongsTo = array('Core', 'File');
```

File has:

```
$belongsTo = 'Core';
$hasOne = 'Form';
```

Core has:

```
$hasOne = array('Form', 'File');
```

EDIT:

So, I went ahead an implemented this idea but now I've got three problems:

1) The form is updating the Form row as expected but also creating a new blank row with a new id.  I don't want this new row.

2) The Form[file_id] foreign key is not being updated, it stays null.

3) My form doesn't validate properly, meaning if I attempt to submit a form with missing fields it just tries to submit the form without showing me the validation errors (all validation rules are set to 'required' and 'rule' = 'notEmpty')

Comment: You have some naming problems in your db. Read this: [Naming convantions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)

Comment: Hi skywalker, the given names aren't the actual names I'm using. The database tables are called cores, directeds, and files. Models are called Core, Directed, and File. All are handled in ProcessesController which loads the models into the function profView, which loads the view prof_view.ctp